# Upgrade Nag - Xubuntu 13.04 (XFCE) continually asks about updating to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, xfce

I've just built a system with Xubuntu 13.04 and it's continually (~ every 15 minutes) asking if I want to upgrade to 13.10.  I hit the "Don't Upgrade" button and it's back again in 15 minutes or so.  Same with the "Ask me later" button.

It's asking this in a small box that can't be expanded and won't let me see the whole thing even with the sliders.

Answer (score 3):

Launch `Software & Updates` from the Settings Manager, on the `Updates` tab, use the bottom drop down menu and select Never.

[image]